# Hover pseudoclass is not working on FontAwesome icon in React

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm quite baffled. Yesterday I did the same thing in the other component and it worked perfectly fine. Let me show you the code...

```
<FontAwesomeIcon onClick={this.displayVerticalNavbar} className="faColorOverwriter" id="toggleInContNavBar" icon={faBars} pull="right"/>

    #toggleInContNavBar:hover{
    height:84%;
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Today, I've been trying to do a similar thing in the other component, and :hover just won't work no matter what. Why do you think it is?

My Present code:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon id="menuSearchElementEdit" icon={faEdit}/>

    #menuSearchElementEdit:hover{
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is work for me. you can add cursor style as below rather than adding different css.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon id="menuSearchElementEdit" icon={faEdit} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: you can apply styles using below code. It's work for me. style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}